# Python/Pandas searching data in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to explain my question with an example. I have a dataset which includes avocado average prices and many features about these prices(I guess avocado prices dataset is very popular, idk). And there is a feature called "region" that shows where avocadoes grew. I wrote this line of code to get to avocados feature which grews on "west". my data's name is data btw

```
west = data[data['region'] =='West']
```

And i thinked that what if i wanted to get the avocadoes which grew in 2016 and also grew on West. How can i get these data at the same time ?

Comment: Can you add few rows of your dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `pandas` DataFrame filter with boolean conditions can solve your question.

Suppose your column name for avocado growing year is `grew_in`. Then try this:

```
west_2016 = data[(data['region'] =='West') & (data['grew_in'] == 2016)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `query` interfrace of `pandas`.

In particular, if your "grew in" data is present in `year` column, you could do something like,

`data.query('region == "West" and year == 2016')`

References:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filtering-data-with-pandas-query-method/

Comment: I've learned a new thing thanks to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
west = data[(data['region']=='west')&(data['year']==2016)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. You solved my problem.